# Configure Protobuf or ProtobufHttpMessageConverter to return null or empty fields

Tags: java, spring-boot, protocol-buffers, grpc-java

Somewhat new to `protobuf` in the java ecosystem I am currently trying to configure an endpoint to return *all* fields, although currently, the endpoint only returns *non-null*, *non-empty*, *non-zero* fields.

Usually, I would do something like configure object mapper in `application.yaml` like so, and I am wondering if there is someway I can configure ProtobufHttpMessageConverter to yield me similar results

```yaml
spring:
  jackson:
    default-property-inclusion: ALWAYS
```

for context, here's my `ProtobufMessageConverterConfig`

```java
@Configuration
public class ProtobufMessageConverterConfig {

  @Bean
  public ProtobufHttpMessageConverter protobufHttpMessageConverter() {
    return new ProtobufHttpMessageConverter();
  }
}
```

and my `Controller` method that returns the model generated from my proto using the standard `grpc-java` plugin:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/assets", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<GetAssetsResponse> getAssets() {

    // do something to populate GetAssetsResponse
    final var reply = GetAssetsResponse.newBuilder().build();

    return new ResponseEntity<>(reply, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

SO, my question is:

1. Can I configure ProtobufMessageConverterConfig to ensure all fields (including 0 or empty fields) get returned in my response or
2. Can/should I add properties to my proto to ensure these fields get populated?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check [ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/protobuf/ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter.html) ? With that you will be able to pass a `JsonFormat.Parser` and `JsonFormat.Printer` and these have much more options. eg: You have `includingDefaultValueFields()` in the Printer.